# Getting Firefox to change the "Homepage" based on day of the week

Tags: firefox, homepage

I guess this is a strange question, but I'd like exactly what I've written in the title. I want to use different "homepages" or "starting pages" in firefox depending on the day of week that the browser is started.

For example, 5 days of the week, the starting page will be URL A.
But 2 days of the week, the starting page will be URL B.

I believe this way URL B won't be getting in my way too much, but I'll still force myself to visit URL B more often.

Any suggestions?

I googled for some firefox extension to use this,  but the only thing I found was "Homepage Randomizer" ( https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/homepage-randomizer/ ), which goes in the right direction, because you can provide multiple homepage URLs, but the URL that is used at a given time depends on random occurrence. That's not so good. Also, the extension is outdated...

Answer (score 1):

Some searches showed that the addon you mentioned and other similar, outdated extensions. I think your best shot is to place a PHP script somewhere on your local computer (or on a remote server, if you wish), that get's the job done of finding the day of week, and redirecting the browser to a page accordingly. You may find some help in making such a script with the guide on `date` at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php. Set your browser homepage to this PHP script. By checking the current day of week and comparing with if...then statements, you can redirect to another page (your actual desired homepage accordingly). I realize there is a bit of a lag between you're browser reaching the PHP script and then redirecting to the respective site, but that's about all I can do for now.

Answer (score 1):

You could use JavaScript to make a simple script that gets the day of the week using the Date.getDay function, and then redirects accordingly. You can then place the script in an HTML file on your local computer and set your Firefox homepage to it. This way, you don't have to rely on an external server and the redirection should be almost instantaneous.